# Standardizing each observation using the mean and standard deviation calculated using only prior observations

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, mean, standard-deviation

I am able to Standardizing each observation for the variable "len" using the mean and standard deviation calculated from only prior observations. However, I am uable to attach it as a column to my dataframe 'tg'.
Can you please help me with this.

This is my data and the code below

```
tg<-structure(list(len = c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 
                           5.2, 7, 16.5, 16.5, 15.2, 17.3, 22.5, 17.3, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 
                           15.5), supp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("OJ", 
                                                                                                             "VC"), class = "factor"), dose = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 

a<-for (i in 1:20) print((a=(tg$len[i]-mean(tg$len[1:i]))/sd(tg$len[1:i])))
a
```

How do I merge 'a' to dataframe 'tg'?

Comment: dataset is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only manipulating the 'len' column, even though the data you provided has been cut off at the end, it doesn't matter.

```
tg <- structure(list(len = c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 
5.2, 7, 16.5, 16.5, 15.2, 17.3, 22.5, 17.3, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 
15.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

library(cgwtools)
library(tidyverse)

mutate(tg, a = (len - cummean(len)) / as.numeric(cumfun(len,FUN=sd)))

    len          a
1   4.2         NA
2  11.5  0.7071068
3   7.3 -0.1000786
4   5.8 -0.4467580
5   6.4 -0.2338041
6  10.0  0.9034338
7  11.2  1.1020545
8  11.2  0.9600072
9   5.2 -0.9995251
10  7.0 -0.3568003
11 16.5  2.1167875
12 16.5  1.7134116
13 15.2  1.2505815
14 17.3  1.5144804
15 22.5  2.0939917
16 17.3  1.0537874
17 13.6  0.3614600
18 14.5  0.5132783
19 18.8  1.2491686
20 15.5  0.6024895
```

Comment: Notice that OP is computing cummean and not just mean ie numerator will be something like: `(x - cummean(x))`. You calculate the mean and standard deviation using  *only prior observations*

Comment: agh brainfart! Thank you @Onyambu

Comment: The `sd` part is incorrect. Its cummulative sd. Not `sd` of the whole data.

Comment: Just letting you know your answer is incorrect compared to what OP desires.

Comment: should be working now

Comment: also, as a sidenote, not a function name you want to google without specifying that you're looking for an R function 

Comment: quite oddly cumfun(len,FUN=scale) gives similar but incorrect results. Unsure why!

Answer (score 1):

You could use existing code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459711/how-to-find-cumulative-variance-or-standard-deviation-in-r/52459826#52459826) to compute the results:

```
tg$a <- (tg$len - cummean(tg$len))/cumvar_cpp(tg$len, TRUE)
tg

   len           a
1   4.2         NA
2  11.5  0.7071068
3   7.3 -0.1000786
4   5.8 -0.4467580
5   6.4 -0.2338041
6  10.0  0.9034338
7  11.2  1.1020545
8  11.2  0.9600072
9   5.2 -0.9995251
10  7.0 -0.3568003
11 16.5  2.1167875
12 16.5  1.7134116
13 15.2  1.2505815
14 17.3  1.5144804
15 22.5  2.0939917
16 17.3  1.0537874
17 13.6  0.3614600
18 14.5  0.5132783
19 18.8  1.2491686
20 15.5  0.6024895
```

---

Copying the code from the site given:

```
cummean <- function (x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)

Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector cumvar_cpp(NumericVector x, bool sd) {
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector v(n);
  srand(time(NULL));
  double pivot = x[rand() % n];
  double *xx = &x[0], *xx_end = &x[n], *vv = &v[0];
  int i = 0; double xi, sum2 = 0.0, sum = 0.0, vi;
  for (; xx < xx_end; xx++, vv++, i++) {
    xi = *xx - pivot;
    sum += xi; sum2 += xi * xi;
    vi = (sum2 - (sum * sum) / (i + 1)) / i;
    if (sd) vi = sqrt(vi);
    *vv = vi;
    }
  return v;
  }')
```